# Detect user selected option on Windows preventing restart C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

So i have a program that runs in background and by accident i found that if you prompt restart and get the screen that some app prevents it if you click cancel my app actually dies. Is there a way to make app wait more or to check what user selected on that screen.

What i meant is this:
[image: RESTART SCREEN PROMPT]

After this screen when i go cancel my app is dead.

Comment: It's an unusual situation but when that screen is shown, processes are *meant* to exit. Trying to hang around longer will just mean your program appears on the list of programs preventing restart.

Comment: Yeah i tried to hold it but it appears on the list, is there a way that i can create some registry key or something that windows will trigger after it kills the app. Since when you click cancel the os does not turn back on startup apps.